# Efficiently merge array data in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two php arrays with different inforrmations related to same entity types (I dont have the choice, the data come from an API like this...).

Here are my two arrays :

```
$array_1 = ['1' => { pId: '273', 'name': 'Thomas' }, '2' => { '2' => { pId: '786', 'name': 'Bryan' }];
$array_2 = ['1' => { pId: '786', 'points': '35' }, '2' => { '2' => { pId: '273', 'points': '18' }, '3' => { pId: '221', 'points': '67' }];
```

If you notice, array_2 also related to players, but has the points attribute that i need to add to array_1 data. I also dont need in my final_array the extra player added in array_2 (with 67 points).

What i want :

```
$final_array = ['1' => { pId: '273', 'name': 'Thomas', 'points': '18' }, '2' => { '2' => { pId: '786', 'name': 'Bryan', 'points' => '35' }];
```

I succeeded in doing that by making a foreach function on both tables but my arrays are quite large (about 600 items) and it is freezing a bit the browser during this filtering.

I wonder if there are some php functions that can merge my tables more efficiently ?

Thank you

Comment: Show us what you currently have first of all. 600 items doesn’t sound that much actually, it is rather hard to imagine that could cause any noticeable delays to begin with (unless you did something really wrong.)

Comment: Does both array have json encoded data? or it's normal php array?

Comment: Is there any logic in the encoding of `'2'` being different to the others?

Comment: Please clarify your data structure, as I'm reading it currently as invalid Php.  If it's JSON pretty print the JSON..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using proper PHP arrays:

```
// create a map of pId => points:
$map = array_column($array_2, 'points', 'pId');

// add the points to the first array
foreach ($array_1 as &$v) {
    $v['points'] = $map[$v['pId']];
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JNNb6)